# Client Web Part for SharePoint Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

G'day there,

Just wondering if someone could advise on this for me? I have a simple sharepoint hosted app and all it is doing is performing simple CRUD operations on a list in the app.

I want to create an app part (client web part) for the app and list the latest additions to the list as well as other links to the app itself...How can I access the content of the list which resides in the App Web from the Client App Part?

Cheers

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

The code (JSOM or REST) which you use to perform CRUD operations will remain the same. You just need to refer the .js file which contains the code inside the new or existing client webpart page.